# jQuery: Display submit button next to selected checkbox

Tags: jquery

I need help with jQuery!

Here's the markup http://jsfiddle.net/MxrqS/16/

What I wanna do is, by default the button "Continue to Step 2" will not be displayed. But when one of the time slot is selected only then the button appears next to the time selected

Anyone can assist me to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can the user only check one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of radiobuttons is preffered in your situation however if you want to continue to use checkboxes the following will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/MxrqS/29/

```
<ul>
    <li id="time1">08:00am - 09:00am <input type="checkbox"> <input type="submit" value="Continue to Step 2" style="display:none" /></li>
<li id="time2">09:00am - 10:00am <input type="checkbox" name="ch1"></li>
<li id="time3">10:00am - 11:00am <input type="checkbox" name="ch2" ></li>
</ul>​
```

JS:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('input[type=checkbox]').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
       $('input[type=submit]').appendTo($(this).parent()).show();
    } else {
         $('input[type=submit]').hide();
    }        
});​
```

Comment: @IwaniKhalid Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved.  Please make sure and select at least one of the answers by clicking the checkmark, if it helped you.

Comment: Yep I will! I'm still thinking hehe :)

Comment: Hahah I did actually state radiobuttons are preferred and upvoted you well prior.  I got lucky on this one.

Comment: Hehe :) I chose @lucuma's answer because he stuck with the checkbox. Nonetheless, you both were helpful and I definitely learnt new things about jQuery :D

Comment: Then maybe this is an improved version of lucima's solution (as a bonus `:)`): http://jsfiddle.net/MxrqS/37/. @IwaniKhalid You can find even more new interesting things about jQuery ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you need these elements to be radio buttons then the solution could be as follows.

*HTML*:

```
<ul>
    <li id="time1">08:00am - 09:00am <input type="radio" name="time"></li>
    <li id="time2">09:00am - 10:00am <input type="radio" name="time"></li>
    <li id="time3">10:00am - 11:00am <input type="radio" name="time"></li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Continue to Step 2" style="display: none;">
```

​
*JavaScript*:

```
$(":radio").on("change", function() {
    $(this).after($(":submit").show());
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MxrqS/24/

Comment: +1 Radiobuttons are preferred if only one needs to be selected as seems to be the case.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm so sorry. You're right, the user can only select one slot and radio button should be used. Thanks for pointing that out! Let me try your code

Comment: Wow!! That's an awesome solution! Thanks a lot @VisioN. Should I be worried about browser compatibility though?

Comment: @IwaniKhalid Nope. jQuery provides cross browser methods. You are welcome! :)